# Flink: How to process rest of finite stream with combination of countWindowAll()

Tags: kotlin, apache-flink

```
//assume following logic
val source = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) // total 12 elements
val env =  StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(1);
val input = env.fromCollection(source)
    .countWindowAll(5)
    .aggregate(...) // pack them to List<Int> for bulk upload to DB
    .addSink(...) // sends bulk
```

When i execute it  - only first 10 processed, but rest 2 elements 
are thrown away  - flink shutdown without processing of them.

The only avoid for me - while i totally controll source data, i can push some well-known IGNORABLE_VALUES to source collection to fit window size and then ignore them in sink... but i think where is some far more professional way in flink.

Answer (score 1):

You have a finite stream of 12 and a window that triggers for every 5 elements. So the first window gets 5 elements and then triggers, then the next 5 are received and it triggers, but the last 2 come and the job knows that no more are going to come. So since there aren't 5 elements in the window the trigger doesn't fire so nothing is done with them.

Comment: Is it possible to express "wait count or timeout" ?